# 'QueryException Array to string conversion' in Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The error says 'QueryException Array to string conversion'.

Find my code below:

CreateProject.php

```
<label for="client_id">Select Client*</label>
<select name="client_name_array" id="">
  @foreach ($clientsArray as $option)
      <option value="{{$option}}">{{$option}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

controller:

```
$projects = new Project([
    'client_name' => $request->input('client_name_array'),
]);
$projects->save();
return redirect('/projects')->with('status', 'Project updated!');
```

Please let me know if you need any further info regarding this query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $clientsArray from where you are getting this variable?

Comment: The Exception suggests that the error is in the ->save() function. Check your $project model. It looks like you are trying to save an array into string. Examine the project before saving using dd($project) and check the variables inside.

Comment: which one throws an exception? the blade template or the controller? which line? please add the whole exception to your message

Comment: I've been struggling on this from past 2 days and was doing some r&d and the issue is solved. When I compare my code with the one I posted, it's the same. Not exactly sure what the problem was and how it got fixed. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this could be the answer.
In CreateProject.php you have used

```
@foreach ($clientsArray as $option)
      <option value="{{$option}}">{{$option}}</option>
  @endforeach
```

Here `$option` is also an array which is being passed as a value to the name `client_name_array`.
 When you submit the form, at the controller, `$request->input('client_name_array')` returns an array. But, the variable `client_name` seems to be of string type in the database. The array type cannot be changed to string type this way. Hope you got my point.

Comment: This form was working fine before, I got this error when I added multiple row and jquery code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Attribute Casting eloquent model feature.
In your `Project` class add

```
protected $casts = [
    'client_name_array' => 'array',
];
```

So the array data will be automatically transformed to string on save and to array on retrieve. 
See [Laravel: Attribute Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)

I have added this to previous answer but then decided to make my own.

Also change this:

```
<select name="client_name_array" id="">
```

to

```
<select name="client_name_array[]" id="">
```

Comment: Thanks Artyom, I did this but no luck. This form was working fine before I added the form with item name, description, price, total and currency. For this I have added jquery code also, something must have gone in newly added code. Please refer to my jquery code, is it correctly scripted?

Comment: Try change input name as in updated answer. If no luck, provide your jquery code and full text of php exception.